# How do I configure the version of Gradle to use with Grails 3.0?

Tags: grails, gradle, grails-3.0

It seems like Grails 3 ships with Gradle 2.3 and I need to downgrade it to 2.2. Is there a way to tell grails to run gradle 2.2 instead of 2.3?

Answer (score 1):

To set the gradle version that grails uses:

1)  First, install your gradle version in a specific location.  As I type this, gradle 2.9 goes with grails 3.1.4, but here are instructions for a gradle 2.2 installation, as you request.

```
a) wget -c http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2-all.zip
b) unzip gradle-2.2-all.zip
c) sudo mv gradle-2.2 /usr/local/gradle-2.2

d) set your GRADLE_HOME environment variable and add GRADLE_HOME/bin to the path.  in your $HOME/.bash_profile or in a /etc/profile.d/gradle.sh file:

    i) GRADLE_HOME=/usr/local/gradle-2.2
   ii) export GRADLE_HOME=$GRADLE_HOME
  iii) PATH=$PATH:$GRADLE_HOME/bin
   iv) export PATH=$PATH

    v) source $HOME/.bash_profile
   vi) gradle -v should say gradle 2.2
```

2) in $HOME/.gradle/gradle.properties, you can set whether or not you want to use the gradle daemon by including a line that says:

```
org.gradle.daemon=true    (gradle will use the daemon when appropriate)

or

org.gradle.daemon=false   (it won't use the daemon)
```

3)  in your project, myproj, which I assume will be in $HOME/projects/myproj

```
$HOME/projects/myproj/gradle.properties should look like:

    grailsVersion=3.1.4       (or whatever version you are using)
    gradleWrapperVersion=2.2     (again, answering your question)
```

4)  in $HOME/projects/myproj/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties, the last line should say:

```
    distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2-all.zip
```

in newer versions, this says gradle-2.9-bin.zip (it's what you originally wget'ed)

5)  finally, 'cd $HOME/projects/myproj' and './gradlew bootRun' to run your project.  or, 'gradle bootRun'.  grails likes to use the wrapper via the ./gradlew command.  Use './gradlew assemble' to build your .war.  if you think you are not running the version you think you should be, use './gradlew clean --refresh-dependencies'.

good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at your *gradle.properties* file?  Mine looks like this:

```
grailsVersion=3.0.11
gradleWrapperVersion=2.3
grails.groovyVersion=2.4.5
```

Not sure about downgrades.  2.3 has worked fine for me so far.